# How to check if there is any “dependence” between columns?

Tags: correlation

How to check if those values are "dependent" ? Take a look on the values in second column coz the difference between them is really huge so it's hard to choose the scale. Any propositions of checking "dependence" between them are welcome. I was thinking about correlation but I am new in statistic so please let me know step by step what should I do to analyse those data.

```
diff    abund_mean
 0   3444804.79
 1   847887.02
 2   93654.19
 0   721692.76
 2   382711.04
 1   428656.65
 1   120933.91
 0   157528.72
 1   159650.70
 0   124602.80
 0   90844.33
 2   501825.37
 1   270592.56
```

I am learning R aswell so I can calculate evertyhing in R if you let me know how to do that.

Comment: There are plenty of sources how to do simple correlation of two columns if you just google it...show some research effort

Comment: Correlation would be best in my case ? What about T-student ?

Comment: If you mean the student's t.test it compares the means of two groups to look for possible difference. Not your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check linear association between the two columns using [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation). The advantage of correlation over [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) is that it is normalised and not dependent on the scales of the column values you are comparing. It takes a value between $-1$ and $1$.

If `diff` and `abund_mean` are numeric sequences, in R:

```
data <- cbind(matrix(diff, ncol=1),matrix(abund_mean, ncol=1)) 
cor(data, use="complete.obs")
```

produces:

```
> cor(dat)
               [,diff]   [,abund_mean]
[diff,]        1.0000000 -0.2813283
[abund_mean,] -0.2813283  1.0000000
```

This is the correlation matrix. As you can see on the diagonals, the correlation of a column-variable with itself is maximum at $1$. The correlation between `diff` and `abund_mean` is negative at $-0.2813283$.